# Does this kind of sketch have a name?

Tags: terminology, sketching

I am trying to determine the general name for this kind of sketch. I've been calling it a frame sketch or a ball-and-stick sketch for some time now, but I'm pretty sure that's wrong (especially since that would get really confusing with animation).

[image: Kangaroo sketch]
[image]

Does anyone know if these actually have a name, or should I just keep making stuff up?

Comment: Geometric Anthropomorphic Minimalist Expression (G.A.M.E.) ? I don't know. This is a good question.

Answer (score 6):

I would call this a ***character wireframe***. [Googling for that term](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS693US693&biw=1920&bih=950&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sketch+character+wireframe&oq=sketch+character+wireframe&gs_l=img.3...3943.5196.0.5364.10.9.0.0.0.0.105.547.8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.img..3.0.0.0njTOMuwSuI) gives images like this:

[image]

[image]

These are often used in ["How to draw X"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS693US693&biw=1920&bih=950&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=how+to+draw+&oq=how+to+draw+&gs_l=img.3..0i67k1l10.5085.5085.0.5464.1.1.0.0.0.0.67.67.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.66.to4Pfm3jLdw) tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply **step-by-step drawing**.
Google search [step-by-step drawing](https://www.google.com/search?q=step%20by%20step%20drawing&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR2NbkrJHgAhXh6eAKHQjiAeYQ_AUIDigB&biw=1533&bih=1200#imgrc=_) and [draw steps](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1533&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=IIRPXLy6JuqGjLsP7ta7wAg&q=draw%20steps&oq=draw%20steps&gs_l=img.3..0i19l2j0i7i30i19l8.44174.44174..44293...0.0..0.78.78.1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.3hkkYtO65bw)

[image]

Comment: There is an explicit 'do not distribute' message in that second image. Are you sure you want to release that into our copyleft license?

Comment: I think this is not any kind of distribution, just a copy link from the source page and I'm not selling it. Maybe I'm wrong.